# How to make a summary from data frame with characters in R

Tags: r

I passed my excel data frame and most variables are in the form of characters.

[image]

I have tried to transform them (starting with the column average) to numeric and make clear the "," meant decimals but it automatically fills all the cells with NA. When I print the data frame again or when I try to do the summary it is only NAs instead of numbers. I got a warning after both trials:

```
class(ArgIncome$Average) <- "numeric"
ArgIncome$Average <- as.numeric(as.character(ArgIncome$Average))
```

saying

> "NAs introduced by coercion".

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Using `read.csv2` with data using a comma as the decimal point should work fine. E.g. `txt <- "Average\n715,8;732,9"; read.csv2(text=txt)` - Would you be able to post a couple of lines of the csv file so the issue can be debugged?

Comment: kind of didnt help but thanks, if I solve this I'll post the solution

Comment: I'm trying to help. Without a line or two of data to test, I can't. Help me help you. Trying to replicate the text as shown in your screenshot doesn't give me the same issue, but Excel might be hiding something that is in the raw csv.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can transform character variable into numeric like this:

```
ArgIncome$Average <- as.numeric(ArgIncome$Average) #if character
ArgIncome$Average <- as.numeric(as.character(ArgIncome$Average)) #if factor
```